# Error authenticating git repository with Redmine

Tags: git, debian-squeeze, redmine

I've setup Redmine 2.1 on my Debian Squeeze server following this Tutorial [HowTo configure Redmine for advanced git integration](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_configure_Redmine_for_advanced_git_integration) (I tried to use the grack path).
Redmine server is running properly, but I have a problem granting users access to git repositories.

When I try to clone a repository it says:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 500 while accessing
```

The apache error.log shows this entry:

```
[Fri Sep 28 15:50:56 2012] [crit] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] configuration error: couldn't check user. Check your authn provider!: /repo.git/info/refs
```

It also asks me for user and password when cloning, but it shouldn't if I understand the tutorial right.

I'm using the Redmine authentication module:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.server.at
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/my.server.at/public" 

    PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine

    <Directory "/var/www/my.server.at/public">
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

        SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER" 
        SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/git/my.server.at/
        SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
        ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName Git
        Require valid-user

        AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
        AuthUserFile /dev/null
        AuthGroupFile /dev/null

        PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
        PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler

        RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine;host=localhost" 

        RedmineDbUser "user" 
        RedmineDbPass "password" 
        RedmineGitSmartHttp yes
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone help me please and explain the error and what I can do to solve my problem?

Comment: Do you have authn_default module loaded?

Comment: authn_default is disabled

Comment: Enable modn_authn_default and mod_auth_basic, restart apache and try again.

Comment: With authn_default enabled I get following error code `access to /repo.git/info/refs failed, reason: verification of user id 'user' not configured`. After setting AuthBasicAuthorative On i get following `user user not found: /repo.git/info/refs`.
Module auth_basic was already enabled. The user 'user' exists in Redmine and can log on the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at my configuration and I have the following.   This has worked well for about a year.

```
PerlLoadModule Apache::Authn::Redmine

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/lib/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Location /git>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
    AuthName "XXXXXX Git Repos"

    PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
    PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler

    RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine_default;host=localhost"
    RedmineDbUser "redmine"
    RedmineDbPass "xxxxxxx"
    RedmineGitSmartHttp yes
</Location>

<Location /git-private>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Limit>
</Location>
```

This is for Ubuntu 12.04.1.  Hope it helps, the main diff is that I am loading Apache::Authn::Redmine and you are loading Apache::Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have following inside of your httpd.conf

```
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
```

I also found this: [Faced with an Internal Server Error for more than an hour | Daniel Stavrovski.Net](https://d.stavrovski.net/post/faced-with-an-internal-server-error-for-more-than-an-hour)